# Error 400 INVALID_ARGUMENT while requesting address book

Tags: python, google-api, google-contacts-api, carddav

I'm setting up the Google Contacts CardDAV API client.

OAuth 2.0 using `oauth2client`.
Request using `requests`.

```
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import requests

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/carddav'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
print(creds.access_token)

hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.access_token}

response = requests.request('PROPFIND', 'https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav', headers=hed, allow_redirects=False)

if response.status_code == 301:
    location = response.headers['location']
    response = requests.request('PROPFIND', 'https://www.googleapis.com' + location, headers=hed)
    print(response.text)
```

But when I request url for get the address book (I get it from `Location` header of first request), it returns error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

## Full requests information

### First request

```
requests.request('PROPFIND', 'https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav', headers=hed, allow_redirects=False)
```

---

```
REQUEST
=======
endpoint: PROPFIND https://www.googleapis.com/.well-known/carddav
headers:
  User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept: */*
  Connection: keep-alive
  Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********************************************
  Content-Length: 0
=======
```

```
RESPONSE
========
status_code: 301
headers:
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Location: /carddav/v1/principals/<my_email>/lists/default/
  Pragma: no-cache
  Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
  Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2019 11:43:23 GMT
  Server: ESF
  Content-Length: 0
  Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
========
```

### Second request

```
response = requests.request('PROPFIND', 'https://www.googleapis.com' + location, headers=hed)
```

---

```
REQUEST
=======
endpoint: PROPFIND https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/<my_email>/lists/default/
headers:
  User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept: */*
  Connection: keep-alive
  Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********************************************
  Content-Length: 0
=======
```

```
RESPONSE
========
status_code: 400
headers:
  Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2019 11:43:23 GMT
  Server: ESF
  Content-Length: 127
  X-XSS-Protection: 0
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
body:
  {
    "error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
  }
========
```

Comment: Hi @artem-batalov, Can you provide some more detail: what does the response from the first PROPFIND request look like? I'd like to know what the full request looks like that is returning the 400.

Comment: Hello @Graeme, I added this details to the post

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: The `PROPFIND` method is generic and must include a body that specifies what information the server should return. You must pass an XML payload in the body of the request that identifies the properties that you are requesting.

#### Getting the addressbooks URIs

According to [Google's CardDav API docs](https://developers.google.com/contacts/carddav/#connecting_to_googles_carddav_server), your first request is perfect and will redirect you to the Address Book Resource for the current user. Here is Google's description of the next step:

> Your client program can then discover the principal address book by performing a PROPFIND on the `addressbook-home-set` and looking for the `addressbook` and `collection` resources.

Let me unpack this: your second request should query a list of the user's resources found at the location you got from the first request. To do this query properly, you'll need to pass an XML body with the `PROPFIND` request, like so:

```
    PROPFIND https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/<my_email>/lists/default/
    Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********************************************
    Depth: 1
    Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

    <D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <D:prop>
         <D:resourcetype />
         <D:displayname />
      </D:prop>
    </D:propfind>
```

Here you specify the properties that you want the server to respond. You specify the `resourcetype` property because you are only interested in `addressbook` or `collection` resources which contain contacts.

This request will return a list of URIs to resources from which you can select any that have a resource type of `addressbook` or `collection`.

At this point, you don't have any contacts or even URIs of contacts. You have a list of URIs for the user's address books or collections of contacts. (Typically, there's just one of these, but there could be many.)

*You didn't ask how to get the user's contacts, but I'm assuming it is your end goal and will continue with the subsequent steps.*

#### Getting the contacts URIs

Your next set of requests will query each of the address book URIs for the URIs of their contacts. Loop over each result from the previous query and issue another `PROPFIND` request on the URI with this payload:

```
    REPORT <addressbook_uri>
    Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********************************************
    Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

    <D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <D:prop>
        <D:getetag />
        <D:getcontenttype />
      </D:prop>
    </D:propfind>
```

Here we query the content type of each item so we can determine if it is a VCard type. VCards are legit contact records.

Now you can filter this set of results by `contenttype == 'text/vcard'` to get a new list of URIs pointing to each contact in the user's address book.

*Oh man, we are getting so close.*

#### Get the contact VCards

Finally, assemble your list of URIs to actual contact data and query the data from the server.

Here you will make an `addressbook-multiget` `REPORT` request to retrieve a batch of the contacts in your list. Google doesn't say how many contact URIs you may include in your request. I've typically limited my request to a few hundred at a time.

E.g.

```
    REPORT <addressbook_uri>
    Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********************************************
    Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

    <C:addressbook-multiget xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
      <D:prop>
        <D:getetag/>
        <C:address-data>
          <C:allprop/>
        </C:address-data>
      </D:prop>
      <D:href>/carddav/v1/principals/<my_email>/lists/default/contact1.vcf</D:href>
      <D:href>/carddav/v1/principals/<my_email>/lists/default/contact2.vcf</D:href>
      ...
    </C:addressbook-multiget>
```

The response will contain the VCard data for each of the contacts, packed inside XML. Parse out the XML text and then parse the VCard data to finally retrieve your contact details.

*Done!*

---

#### Resources:

- [Google's limited CardDav docs](https://developers.google.com/contacts/carddav/)
- The best resource I've found is [this description of building a CardDav client by Sabre](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-carddav-client/)
- When others fail, go to the source: [RFC6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352)

Comment: This step "Get the contact VCards" does not work for now.

Does Google CardDav has any change on the addressbook-multiget request?